# Issue with IIF function in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am looking at a few lines of VB code and am not sure why the last `WriteLine` is failing. It seems as if the `ToUpper()` function is trying to be evaluated (will work if not calling this function on the string) even if the condition clearly evaluates to false and should just output the "mydefault" hard coded string in this example.  I know that the `Nothing` keyword is similar to the `default` in C# but I think the issue really lies with how the `IIF` function evaluates it's trees.

Does anyone know the reason this code throw the NullReferenceException?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim x As String = "a"
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("y:{0}", IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) OrElse x Is Nothing, "mydefault", x.ToUpper())))

        Dim y As String = String.Empty
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("z:{0}", IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) OrElse y Is Nothing, "mydefault", y.ToUpper())))

        Dim z As String = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("x:{0}", IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(z) OrElse z Is Nothing, "mydefault", z.ToUpper())))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: As you said, it is a *Function*.  A function call forces all arguments to be evaluated, there is no short-circuiting.  Kaboom.

Comment: touché, didn't think abou it like this. If that is the case then I wonder how the IF function prevents against this?

Comment: It is a keyword, not a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIF is a relic and evaluates both conditions as you describe. Try using If instead.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim x As String = "a"
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("y:{0}", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) OrElse x Is Nothing, "mydefault", x.ToUpper())))

        Dim y As String = String.Empty
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("z:{0}", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) OrElse y Is Nothing, "mydefault", y.ToUpper())))

        Dim z As String = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("x:{0}", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(z) OrElse z Is Nothing, "mydefault", z.ToUpper())))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Cool, thanks man. What do you mean by relic, legacy.old code?

Comment: No problem! IIF is from the VB6 days and I believe was preserved for compatibility.

Comment: Isn't  `OrElse x Is Nothing` redundant? You could also use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in case there's chance the string contains only spaces.

Comment: @OneFineDay - I just wish MS would default VB.Net to use Option Strict On for all new projects!  That alone would help tremendously!

Comment: @JoshPart, they must have grown up with it. I did not and don't use them. In the grand scheme those are pretty low numbers - less than *0.001%* of the community - close guess based on millions of users.

Comment: @OneFineDay I know the numbers may seem low, but I believe an opinion based solely on numbers was Microsoft's first mistake when deciding to leave VB6 behind (second was let users believe VB.Net was it's new version). Windows 8 support for VB6 programs proves that numbers might not be accurate. Of course it is not a great language and there are many, many more better, but it was and is good for it's main purpose: create simple, fully functional systems in and hour - or less. That's what I think MS should bring back.

Comment: OrElse x Is Nothing is redundant, I was just trying different things out here